# How can I intagrate cucumber into Puppeteer tests writen in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, cucumber, jestjs, cucumberjs

I have an extensive amount of test cases written with Jest-Puppeteer in Type Script, is there anyway to integrate cucumber with the tests I already have?

Cucumber doesn't seem to ready my step-definition files when its in .ts file format. .js file formats work as expected but I cant import sections of code from all the .ts files already there.

Has anyone got any examples or how I can setup a config file for cucumber to read .ts files?